# Facebook Send Dialog error 500 only for some facebook UserIDs

Tags: facebook

I'm using Facebook UI Send Dialog so the users of my website can share a link with their friends. The link includes the Facebook User ID in the query string. Everything works fine except for a few users that have reported errors.

To test this, I considered to cases: one for a Facebook user that can use the Send Dialog without a problem, and another for a user that reported the error. I used two identical calls to Fb, only changing the userID and, as described previously, one worked and the other didn't.

This works ok:

> https:// www.facebook.com/dialog/send?access_token=XXXXXX&app_id=XXXXXX&channel=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2FZEbdHPQfV3x.js%3Fversion%3D41%23cb%3Df1adbecbf8%26domain%3D3Dmyworkingurl.com%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252F3Dmyworkingurl.com%252Ff524fe64%26relation%3Dparent.parent&channel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2FZEbdHPQfV3x.js%3Fversion%3D41%23cb%3Df2c646879%26domain%3D3Dmyworkingurl.com%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252F3Dmyworkingurl.com%252Ff524fe64%26relation%3Dparent.parent&description=pruebafb&display=iframe&e2e=%7B%7D&link=https%3A%2F%2F3Dmyworkingurl.com%2F%3Ffbid%3D**WorkingFbUserId**&locale=es_LA&next=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2FZEbdHPQfV3x.js%3Fversion%3D41%23cb%3Df206f6e03%26domain%3D3Dmyworkingurl.com%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252F3Dmyworkingurl.com%252Ff524fe64%26relation%3Dparent%26frame%3Df34cf0b14%26result%3D%2522xxRESULTTOKENxx%2522&sdk=joey&to=XXXXXXXXX

This returns a HTTP Error 500:

> https:// www.facebook.com/dialog/send?access_token=XXXXXX&app_id=XXXXXX&channel=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2FZEbdHPQfV3x.js%3Fversion%3D41%23cb%3Df17fb992a8%26domain%3Dmyworkingurl.com%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252F3Dmyworkingurl.com%252Ff271eb6f14%26relation%3Dparent.parent&channel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2FZEbdHPQfV3x.js%3Fversion%3D41%23cb%3Df28b526904%26domain%3D3Dmyworkingurl.com%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252F3Dmyworkingurl.com%252Ff271eb6f14%26relation%3Dparent.parent&description=pruebafb&display=iframe&e2e=%7B%7D&link=https%3A%2F%2F3Dmyworkingurl.com%2F%3Ffbid%3D**NotWorkingFbUserId**&locale=es_LA&next=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2FZEbdHPQfV3x.js%3Fversion%3D41%23cb%3Df184d49ae%26domain%3D3Dmyworkingurl.com%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252F3Dmyworkingurl.com%252Ff271eb6f14%26relation%3Dparent%26frame%3Df567db08%26result%3D%2522xxRESULTTOKENxx%2522&sdk=joey&to=XXXXXXXXX

I tested the link urls using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ and both returned Response code 200.

Do you have an idea on why is this happening only for some users even when they return a successful response using the Facebook debugger?
Thanks :)

Comment: Where did you get the user id from?

Comment: From my database. When a user links their facebook account to my app, I store the UserID and this is the one I am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you are suffering from this bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1478339672437492/

The bug was already seen by Facebook Team and it is already assigned to someone to solve. I know this because unfortunately it affected me too.

As this is affecting a lot of developers, I guess it won't take too long to be fixed.

---

To be in record for future Google searches, this was the bug:

> Since this morning the FB Send Dialog redirects to an empty page
>   regardless of the parameters. Even the example from the documentation
>   (
>
> FB.ui({   method: 'send',   link:
>   'http://www.nytimes.com/2011/06/15/arts/people-argue-just-to-win-scholars-assert.html',
>   });
>
> http://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?   app_id=123050457758183
>   &link=http://www.nytimes.com/2011/06/15/arts/people-argue-just-to-win-scholars-assert.html
>   &redirect_uri=https://www.bancsabadell.com/cs/Satellite/SabAtl/
>
> )
>
> is not working anymore. Please see into this, thank you very much.
>
> Last known working date: September 22, 2014

---

According to Facebook it should now be solved:

> Øyvind Sean Kinsey ·  · Facebook Platform Team
>
> This should now be resolved. Thanks for your
>   patience.
>   2 hours ago · Status changed to Fixed

Comment: It's is working fine now. It seems that it was actually that bug. Thanks